# Creating a class with declared attributes on Safari does not work

Tags: javascript, safari

I have a piece of code bellow and i cannot seem to make it work on Safari.

```js
class handlePdf {
    url             = null;
    wrapper_element = null;
    pdfDoc          = null;
    pageNum         = 1;
    pageRendering   = false;
    pageNumPending  = null;
    scale           = 0.55;
    canvas          = null;
    ctx             = null;
    pdfjsLib        = null;
    parent          = this;

    constructor(options) {
      this.url = options.url;
      this.wrapper_element = options.wrapper_element;

      this.canvas = document.getElementById(this.wrapper_element),
      this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    }
...
```

Safari gives an error at the first "=" i have read all the docs and it seems to be correct. I'm stuck, can anybody point me at some direction?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Field_declarations

Comment: Well, i modified my class and still does not work.

Comment: I'm using arrow functions, maybe is that it?

Comment: Public and private field is not yet supported in all browsers, if you still want then use [babel](https://babeljs.io) to convert it to es5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As class field declarations are not a standard you can either use [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile your code
Or don't use them and refactor your class to something like:

```js
class handlePdf {
    constructor(options) {
      this.init()
      this.url = options.url;
      this.wrapper_element = options.wrapper_element;

      this.canvas = document.getElementById(this.wrapper_element),
      this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    }

    init() {
      this.url             = null;
      this.wrapper_element = null;
      this.pdfDoc          = null;
      this.pageNum         = 1;
      this.pageRendering   = false;
      this.pageNumPending  = null;
      this.scale           = 0.55;
      this.canvas          = null;
      this.ctx             = null;
      this.pdfjsLib        = null;
      this.parent          = this;
    }
...
```

Comment: Yeah i figured. I passed that point, but i was using arrow functions so, with no surprise, Safari is not good at it too. I changed to all functional and it worked!

Comment: If your still at the start of your project I would advise setting up babel, it's pretty awesome ;)